# Excel - Copy between two workbooks in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks in excel. I am trying to copy a worksheet from one workbook to another. 
And after that I want to close the workbook where I had copied from.
What I have done so far:

`Sub copy()
    Workbooks.Open filename:= _
        "C:\2016.xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Grafic").Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("C:\Grafic.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub`

Thanks.

Comment: The one you want to close is `2016.xlsm`?

Comment: I get the error : "Index out of range", i am searching for a reason since 2 hours I hope someone has a solution for me.

Comment: exactly @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Use F8 to step through the code. Then provide the error message and the line where it stops.

Comment: it stops at line `Selection.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("C:\Grafic.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`
 here I get the message out of range. I am so confused

Comment: You want to copy the complete sheet, right?

Comment: Yes the whole Sheet! @Storax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyIt()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim copyWb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim fileName As String, sheetName As String

    fileName = "... complete filename ..."
    sheetName = "... sheet name ..."

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName)
    Set wks = wb.Sheets(sheetName)

    Set copyWb = ThisWorkbook ' the workbook you would like to copy to
    wks.copy before:=copyWb.Sheets(1)

    wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Storax, when I execute your code I got an error at  "Set copyWb = C:\", I changed it to "Set copyWb = Application.Workbooks("C:\") and then I get the message : out of range

Comment: There is no line Set copyWb = C:\" in the code I provided

Comment: OH my god ! it works!! Thats cool ! I have another short question let's say I have more workbooks with the same worksheet (in more folders), and I want to copy all of them. Shall I use a for each loop for that?

Comment: Under the circumstances you describe you probably cannot use a for each loop but maybe it's better to create a new question with more detailed information on the situation and what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Application.Workbooks("2016.xlsm").Close
```

`Close` method has some parameters to set if you want to save changes or not.

More info:

[Workbook.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-close-method-excel)